# Using xargs to pipe password into command

Tags: passwords, zsh, xargs

Is there a more appropriate means than xargs to add a password from [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) (unix password manager) to a command which includes a password as an option? I'm using iTerm2 with ohmyzsh on macOS. Here is what I have come up with:

```
pass example_password | xargs -I {} unar example_file.7z -p {}
```

In the example, I'm attempting to unarchive an encrypted 7z (something I have to do regularly).

Previously, I had the password (which is always the same for the files I'm dealing with) saved as an environment variable in my .zprofile – while I gather this is bad practice, and obviously leaves the password unencrypted and accessible, it seemed a little less kludgy.

Is there a more straightforward way of doing this? Apologies if this is a very obvious question, I'm new to using shell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.